# Elasticsearch api combine range and tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 elk working queries:

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "range":{
      "timestamp":{
        "gt": "now-15m"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "tags" : "mytag" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I combine this 2 queries? Basically I want to retrieve all the documents in the last 15 minutes with a tag equals to 'mytag'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both of them using `must` and `filter`. When the first give  you the `tags` which you need and the second filter to the given time range. (BTW I went on with your schema but I remember you should look `timestamp` with `@timestamp`)

```
GET _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "match" : { "tags" : "mytag" }
      },
     "filter": 
        {
          "range": {
            "timestamp": {
               "gt": "now-15m"
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}
```